# How to restrict a session to a directory only in PHP?

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

I have an admin system and a user system on my website. Some data on the user system will not change, but the admin data will change instead. So I was wondering if there was a way to restrict the admin session (when they login) only to the admin directory (/admin), so that it does not interfere with the rest of my website?

Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: The question is not clear enough

Comment: nope, it can express more than one particular problem PS: there is no "folders" in http - the wrong terms is the first thing that confuses the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to handle something like this. Probably the easiest is to check the permissions and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and if the user isn't in the `admin/` area, redirect into it.

```
// Assuming you've saved an admin flag in session
// and the user request URI doesn't contain admin/
if ($_SESSION['admin'] === TRUE && !preg_match('/admin\//' $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  // redirect into the admin/ area
  header("Location: http://example.com/admin");
  exit();
}
```

#### Update:

By popular request, here's the reverse to enforce an admin login in the admin/ directory

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['admin'] || $_SESSION['admin'] === FALSE)  && preg_match('/admin\//' $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  // redirect out of the admin/ area
  header("Location: http://example.com/");
  exit();
}
```

Actually, assuming the admin pages are separate scripts, you don't really need the `preg_match()` in this part. But if you have an MVC pattern where the admin script may not actually be served from a file in the admin directory, use the regex match.

Comment: +1 and you should do it the other way round too, like in my answer, so that non-admins can't access the admin area.

Comment: yep, thank you! I was looking for an answer in something like session_start(). But it still works anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not a solution, but it is a workaround. You can use same session for this too. Just create the session identifier for each path at the path name as

```
$_SESSION['path/to/admin']['var1'] = 'value1';
$_SESSION['path/to/admin']['var2'] = 'value2';
```

Such way, you can retrieve the value of path independent session variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`session_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) before calling [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). In that you may be able to differentiate between user and admin areas.

- User

  ```
  session_name("user");
  session_start();
  ```
- Admin

  ```
  session_name("admin");
  session_start();
  ```

Comment: Well then how do I check on this session_name() thing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question completely, but you can always check if the user is an admin, and if not, just redirect them from the admin system to the user system.

Comment: If you didn't understand, you can ask in the comment. Not answer blindly