# Restricting PHP session variables

Tags: php, session

I am working on my localhost and I have two applications running there.

Let's say the urls are:

1. localhost/apps/app1/
2. localhost/apps/app2/

Each of the applications have there own login module which is using PHP based sessions to restrict/allow user to enter the application. The name of session variable is same i.e. `uid`. The way I am using it is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["uid"]))
    header('location:login/index.php');
?>
```

But the session variable of app1 is working and accessible in app2, which I don't want. How can I restrict the accessibility of session variable created in app1 so that it doesn't interfere with the other session variable.

I read this [How to restrict a session to a directory only in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062829/how-to-restrict-a-session-to-a-directory-only-in-php) but this won't work in my case as it is for one directory only.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a session-based application property, e.g., `$_SESSION['current_app']` and check against that on an application basis?

Comment: This is not really restricting the $_SESSION variable to your directory, but you could always use the $_SESSION variable like this, and handle the rest yourself : 
    $_SESSION['apps1']['uid'];
    $_SESSION['apps2']['uid'];

Comment: @DavidWyly Can't I use the same name and restrict the scope of session variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use different names for the sessions when calling `session_start()` by using the options array (more information: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php ), e.g.:

```
// App 1
session_start(['name' => 'Session1']);

// App 2
session_start(['name' => 'Session2']);
```

This results in different session cookie names and finally in completely separated sessions.

Comment: Can't I use the same name and restrict the scope of session variable?

Comment: You can't. Having completely different sessions (with different hashes and different cookie names) is by far the best (and safest) solution.